# Plotting maps using Matplotlib with a loop: Only two of four iterations completing

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib

Using two different dataframes (`Itis` and `Myyrmanni`), I'm attempting to use a loop to plot four different maps with Matplotlib. Each respective dataframe is to be represented with two different maps: travel times from the `Itis`/`Myyrmanni` shopping mall by public transportation and car, respectively. Here's the `Myyrmanni` dataframe; `Itis` looks the relatively the same.

[image]

Even though the `Itis` columns plot correctly, I'm unsure of how to properly plot the following `Myyrmanni` maps. I've attempted to point to specific columns in my `items` list, but they don't plot correctly, as they don't include specific geometric or coordinate data. Another attempt included a nested loop specifically focusing on doing the same process but for the `Myyrmanni` dataset alone, but it results in an infinite loop.

```
fig3, ax_list = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))
ax_list = ax_list.flatten()

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    p = ax_list[i]
    item.plot(column='pt_r_t_cl', ax=p, cmap='autumn') # Plot Public Transit columns in both dfs
    item.plot(column='car_r_t_cl', ax=p, cmap='autumn') # Plot Car columns in both dfs
    ax_list[i].set_title(title)
```

[image]